# Prolog arithmetic in foreach

Tags: math, scope, prolog

So I'm learning Prolog.  One of the things I've found to be really obnoxious is demonstrated in the following example:

```
foreach(
  between(1,10,X),
  somePredicate(X,X+Y,Result)
).
```

This does not work.  I am well aware that X+Y is not evaluated, here, and instead I'd have to do:

```
foreach(
  between(1,10,X),
  (
    XPlusY is X + Y,
    somePredicate(X, XPlusY, Result)
  )
).
```

Except, that doesn't work, either.  As near as I can tell, the scope of `XPlusY` extends outside of `foreach` - i.e., `XPlusY is 1 + Y, XPlusY is 2 + Y,` etc. must all be true AT ONCE, and there is no XPlusY for which that is the case.  So I have to do the following:

```
innerCode(X, Result) :-
  XPlusY is X + Y,
  somePredicate(X, XPlusY, Result).
...

foreach(
  between(1,10,X),
  innerCode(X, Result)
).
```

This, finally, works.  (At least, I think so.  I haven't tried this *exact* code, but this was the path I took earlier from "not working" to "working".)  That's fine and all, except that it's exceptionally obnoxious.  If I had a way of evaluating arithmetic operations in-line, I could halve the lines of code, make it more readable, and NOT create a one-use clutter predicate.

**Question: Is there a way to evaluate arithmetic operations in-line, without declaring a new variable?**

Failing that, it would be acceptable (and, in some cases, still useful for other things) if there were a way to restrict the scope of new variables.  Suppose, for instance, you could define a block within the `foreach`, where the variables visible from the outside were marked, and any other variables in the block were considered new for that execution of the block.  (I realize my terminology may be incorrect, but hopefully it gets the point across.)  For example, something resembling:

```
foreach(
  between(1,10,X),
  (X, Result){
    XPlusY is X + Y,
    somePredicate(X, XPlusY, Result)
  }
).
```

A possible solution might be if we can declare a lambda in-line, and immediately call it.  Summed up:

**Alternate question: Is there a way to limit the scope of new variables within a predicate, while retaining the ability to perform lasting unifications on one or more existing variables?**

(The second half I added as clarification in response to an answer about `forall`.)

A solution to both questions is preferred, but a solution to either will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

library([yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)) allows you to define lambda expressions. For instance

```
?- foreach(between(1,3,X),call([Y]>>(Z is Y+1,writeln(Z)),X)).
2
3
4
true.
```

Alternatively, library([lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda)) provides the construct:

```
?- [library(lambda)].
true.

?- foreach(between(1,3,X),call(\Y^(Z is Y+1,writeln(Z)),X)).
2
3
4
true.
```

In SWI-Prolog, library(yall) is autoloaded, while to get library(lambda) you should install the related pack:

```
?- pack_install(lambda).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in alternative the `forall/2` de facto standard predicate:

```
forall(
  between(1,10,X),
  somePredicate(X,X+Y,Result)
).
```

While the `foreach/2` predicate is usually implemented in the way you describe, the `forall/2` predicate is defined as:

```
% forall(@callable, @callable)

forall(Generate, Test) :-
    \+ (Generate, \+ Test).
```

Note that the use of negation implies that no bindings will be returned when a call to the predicate succeeds.

**Update**

Lambda libraries allow the specification of both lambda global (aka lambda free) and lambda local variables (aka lambda parameters). Using Logtalk lambdas syntax (available also in SWI-Prolog in `library(yall)`, you can write (reusing Carlo's example) e.g.

```
?- G = 2, foreach(between(1,3,X),call({G}/[Y]>>(Z is Y+G,writeln(Z)),X)).
3
4
5
G = 2.

?- G = 4, foreach(between(1,3,X),call({G}/[Y]>>(Z is Y+G,writeln(Z)),X)).
5
6
7
G = 4.
```

Thus, it's possible to use lambdas to limit the scope of some variables within a goal without also limiting the scope of every unification in the goal.

Comment: 1.  The arithmetic doesn't work.  Even using `forall`, if `somePredicate` tries to use `X+Y` in a place where an integer is expected, it still throws the error `ERROR: Type error: 'integer' expected, found '1+1' (a compound)`.  2.  I see that technically this does limit the scope of new variables within the predicate, but it also limits the scope of EVERY unification in the predicate.  I do still need it to bind specific variables, so `forall` is not what I'm looking for; thanks.  I'll update the question with that addendum.