# Prolog concise foreach

Tags: scope, prolog

I'm trying to use Prolog's `foreach` in a concise manner.  For instance, suppose I have a list, and I want to see if it's symmetric.  Consider the following code:

```
isSymmetricList1(Size, List) :-
  foreach(between(1, Size, I1), (
    I2 is Size - I1 + 1,
    nth1(I1, List, Elem),
    nth1(I2, List, Elem)
  )).

isSymmetricList2Sub1(Size, List, I1) :-
  I2 is Size - I1 + 1,
  nth1(I1, List, Elem),
  nth1(I2, List, Elem).

isSymmetricList2(Size, List) :-
  foreach(between(1, Size, I1), (
    isSymmetricList2Sub1(Size, List, I1)
  )).
```

Consider some test cases:

```
?- isSymmetricList1(4,[0,0,0,0]).
false.

?- isSymmetricList1(4,[0,0,0,1]).
false.

?- isSymmetricList1(4,[1,2,2,1]).
false.

?- isSymmetricList1(4,List).
false.

?- isSymmetricList2(4,[0,0,0,0]).
true.

?- isSymmetricList2(4,[0,0,0,1]).
false.

?- isSymmetricList2(4,[1,2,2,1]).
true.
```

`isSymmetricList1` fails, returning only `false` even for lists that are symmetric.  My understanding of why this is is that `I2` is effectively within the scope of `isSymmetricList1`, and therefore can only have one value across all 4 iterations, which is inconsistent with its purpose.  In `isSymmetricList2`, I bind `I2` in `isSymmetricList2Sub1`, taking it out of the scope of `isSymmetricList2`, effectively allowing it to be bound to multiple values (because they're different instances, or however it's said).

This works.  However, it incurs clutter.  I don't really want a bunch of sub-rules floating around my namespace.  [I know there's a lambda module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529245/prolog-arithmetic-in-foreach), and maybe that's simply what I have to use, but I'm interested to know if it's strictly required.  (Also, its syntax is a little tricky.)  Is it possible to use `foreach` to perform an action more complicated than a single goal, without adding extra rules to the namespace, and without importing extra modules?  For instance, if you could declare local rules, or limit the scope of a binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a side note, not addressing your concerns about `foreach/2` usage.

Isn't your definition of symmetric list just proving that a list and its reverse are the same?

```
symmetric_list(List) :-
    reverse(List, List).
```

Sample calls:

```
|?- symmetric_list([0,0,0,0]).
yes

| ?- symmetric_list([0,0,0,1]).
no

| ?- symmetric_list([1,2,2,1]).
yes
```

You can also generate symmetric lists:

```
| ?- symmetric_list(List).
List = [] ;
List = [_16114] ;
List = [_16114, _16114] ;
List = [_16114, _16126, _16114] ;
List = [_16114, _16126, _16126, _16114]
...
```

Regarding the `foreach/2` versus `forall/2` predicates as mentioned in the comments and in one of the other answers, they are used in distinct scenarios. The `forall/2` predicate is a de facto standard predicate that implements a *generate and test* loop. A `forall/2` goal is true when, for all solutions of the first argument, the second argument is true. This implicitly requires backtracking into the generator argument and thus the standard definition of the predicate using negation:

```
forall(Generate, Test) :- \+ (Generate, \+ Test).
```

The use of negation results in `forall/2` returning no bindings. When those bindings are necessary, the `foreach/2` predicate is a possible alternative. Not wanting to rephrase here the documentation on this predicate, I suggest that you consult the documentation of Prolog systems, such as SWI-Prolog and SICStus Prolog, providing it.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the `reverse` function.  It was just an example, though; I'm more interested in the `foreach` part.

Comment: @Erhannis The `reverse/2` **predicate** is commonly found in a Prolog system library.

Comment: @Erhannis Updated my answer with some notes on `foreach/2` versus `forall/2`.

Answer (score 1):

The most glaring problem is that `foreach/2` is not what you seem to want. First, let's do the minimal fix to your `isSymmetricList1/2` that will make it not fail on your examples:

```
isSymmetricList1(Size, List) :-
  forall(between(1, Size, I1), (
    I2 is Size - I1 + 1,
    nth1(I1, List, Elem),
    nth1(I2, List, Elem)
  )).
```

Can you spot the difference?

With this definition, I get:

```
?- isSymmetricList1(4,[0,0,0,0]).
true.

?- isSymmetricList1(4,[0,0,0,1]).
false.

?- isSymmetricList1(4,[1,2,2,1]).
true.
```

You seem to understand exactly why `foreach/2` does what it does and why it fails. I suspect you also know that using `forall/2` would have solved your "problem". The difficult question is, how do we know when we need the one and when the other? I don't think I really know the answer so we'll have to wait for the experts to come and explain it to both of us.

Instead, I will nitpick on the more accessible topics that your question raises.

You realize this is a really round-about way of doing what you are doing, right? First, you go through the whole list, comparing each pair of elements *twice*. Then, `nth1/3` has to traverse the list from its start every time you call it.

About "sub-rules floating in your namespace", this is not such a bad thing after all. Helper predicates help you think about relations. They also give you a great opportunity for documenting your intent through the predicate names.

Which kinda makes me wanna start talking about naming and camelCase in particular and how you shouldn't do it, but this is too far off topic.

Comment: Oh, actually, I didn't know that `forall/2` would have worked.  Testing it out, though, I'm starting to remember that I didn't like it in the past because you can't use it to bind things, like in `isSymmetricList(4,[1,2,A,B])` or whatever.  Maybe that's the fundamental problem: `foreach` binds and `forall` doesn't, but what I wanted was something specific inbetween.  I also wasn't aware of the inefficiencies.  What would be a better way of expressing this?  (I'm not really convinced about the namespace or case issues, being a native Java writer, but I think we can ignore those issues.)

Comment: @Erhannis well being a poor soul who has to read and write Java in a codebase written by "Java writers" daily, let's indeed forget about the namespace and case issues, then we can still communicate as civilized people. About efficiency: first, you need to stop at the middle of the list. You'd do the same in Java, wouldn't you? Then, imagine you're dealing with a `LinkedList`: how would you do it? Maybe traverse it to the half, reverse the second half, then compare the two? Once I start doing such acrobatics, I usually stop and think about the larger problem at hand.

Comment: @Erhannis `forall/2` vs. `foreach/2`: do you need the bindings or are they getting in the way? This sounds like a pretty good question if you have to decide. I wonder what is the "specific thing inbetween". Like, you don't need the bindings but you'd like to have them just in case? Or you kinda need them but then again they get in the way?

Comment: By "specific thing inbetween" I mean that, in this case, I want the binding of `List` to propagate back up, but the binding of `I2` to stay local to the three lines where it's relevant. Probably the most natural expression of what I'd like `foreach` to do is that if a variable is referenced inside a `foreach`, and not in the surrounding scope, then the variable's binding stays restricted to within each iteration of the `foreach`, and not shared between them and/or outside them. Kinda like the scope of variable declarations in other languages. Seems like this isn't available, though.

Comment: Also, re: optimization, yeah, I kindof stopped thinking about efficiency when traveling to Prolog Land, because it's so algorithmically different than the other languages I know.  It LOOKS like it's purely symbolic, and order-invariant.  ...But (I was disappointed to discover) it's a bit of a facade, and in the background it just iterates through the possible combinations, in order.  (Which may be one reason the constraint libraries were created.)  Feels kinda like a heap of auto-optimizations could be used, but instead they made their implementation details part of their API.

Comment: @Erhannis In this case, it was not about optimization; it was about algorithmic complexity. And Prolog is just a programming language.

Comment: Reducing your algorithmic complexity is an important form of optimization.  And yeah, but for instance, operators like `cut` make backtracking an explicitly defined component of the language.  I assert (without proof) that Prolog as a language could be defined without acknowledging the existence of backtracking, and that doing so would allow an implementation of Prolog more freedom to e.g. swap around expressions and condense logically redundant statements, etc.  (I've never used the chat, but we could move there if you want to continue discussing.)